# Azure Application Insights On Azure Service Fabric with Performance Counter

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

On existing Azure Service Fabric Instance, recently incorporated the "Azure Application Insights" using below code

```
 return new WebHostBuilder().UseHttpSys()
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                                    .AddSingleton<ServiceFabricAppContext>(new ServiceFabricAppContext(){
                                            NodeName = serviceContext.NodeContext.NodeName,
                                            ServiceHostIP=serviceContext.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN,
                                            ServiceHostPort=FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoints()[0].Port
                                    } )
                                        .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>((serviceProvider) => FabricTelemetryInitializerExtension.CreateFabricTelemetryInitializer(serviceContext))) // Azure Service Fabric Telemetry Initializer
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                               .UseApplicationInsights()
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseEnvironment(environment)
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
```

Basically added just below one line of additional code ie.,

```
 .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>((serviceProvider) => FabricTelemetryInitializerExtension.CreateFabricTelemetryInitializer(serviceContext)))
```

Below are additional packages added,

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native" Version="2.1.1" /> 
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal" Version="4.1.417" />
```

Right now under AzureApplicationInsights => logs, only "requests" table having data where as other required tables especially "performanceCounters" is empty.

What needs to be done/configured, so that already wired Azure Application insights instance can record performance Counters details like CPU, memory etc of existing service fabric nodes, which are hosting .Net Core 2.1 Web Api application?

**Code used to get performance counters:**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector;

public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
   var aiOptions = new  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions
  .ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();

  aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
  aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true;
  aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = "cxxxxxx4-2xx6-xxx1-axxf-071xxxxxxxb";
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

// The following configures PerformanceCollectorModule.
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<PerformanceCollectorModule>((module) =>
{
    // the application process name could be "dotnet" for ASP.NET Core self-hosted applications.
    module.Counters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(
    @"\Process([**_dotnet_**])\Page Faults/sec", "DotnetPageFaultsPerfSec")); //not sure "dotnet" is right value here?
});

  //Add MVC
  services.AddMvcCore(options =>
  {
    options.Filters.Add(new 
    LoggingFilter(_container.GetInstance<IMemoryCache>()));
  });
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get telemetry from the cluster nodes, you'll need to deploy the OMS agent to each node.
Make sure to deploy Application Insights with a [separate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource) log analytics store, so you can use the same store for both data sets.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-agent).

Comment: Cant we achieve with it 'code', without Agent?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource#code-based-application-monitoring

Comment: afaik you need the agents to gather details about the node and upload it to Log Analytics or use [WAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad)

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps#enable-application-insights  Application Insights Agent is currently supported only .Net IIS-hosted applications.

Comment: I think you're mixing application telemetry with OS telemetry there. The agent / vm extension will only gather machine info, not application info. The application info comes from your code (you have that in place).

Comment: I think you are right I have mixed application telemetry with OS telemetry. Actually I want to know what specifically limits the load the SF cluster nodes? what is the best option that Azure application supports to know cpu, memory usage in the nodes?

Comment: yes, that, combined with I/O (network, disk). I believe the agent or extension will be able to gather that telemetry for you. Then combine that with some clever LA kusto queries to get insights.

Comment: @ LoekD - without using agent or extension, recently used "Code to get performance counters" mentioned the code used in my post along with these nuuget packages  ("Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" Version="2.15.0" &
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.8.2") on my .net core 2.1 WebAPI project which in turn runs Azure SF cluster to get performance counters & its working. Attached the performance counters screenshot for your reference. Is these performance counters values are reliable as they are not from specific agent or extension? please clarify

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters#collecting-performance-counters-in-code-for-aspnet-core-web-applications

Comment: You'd mix responsibilities (monitoring the system from within the system). If your service has an issue and cannot start, you'll have no telemetry about the node. By delegating this work to an agent, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for the insight view. The reason for programmatic approach (or) monitoring the system from within the system is, adding monitoring agent to existing VM scale set on PROD requires downtime. Downtime is not allowed in our PROD system. Also in our PROD deployment there is no stand-by/secondary replica of SF cluster, to take load momentarily when primary cluster down. Is there any way we can add monitoring agent to VM scale set without downtime? BTW you have mentioned about VM Extension for perf. counters monitoring, can you please provide VM Extension related reference docs link?

Comment: That's the [WAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad) link above :-)